# Neo4j match... merge cypher syntax for UPSERT is returning (no rows)

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I just started learning GraphDB with Neo4j yesterday, Now, I want to perform an UPSERT operation as shown below;

```
match (circle:Circle {id:3, cycleId:5})
merge (member1:Member {id:1}) -[invited:INVITED_TO_JOIN {c:circle, time:timestamp()}]-> (member2:Member {id:2})
return member1, member2, invited, circle
```

According to the docs here http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html if the node ***circle*** with the assigned properties does not exist then the node and the specified relationship should be created, otherwise, an update should be performed on the node and relationships. however this does not happen. I only get a rsponse that says `(no rows)`. see below;

[image]

Could someone please point to me what I'm probably not doing correctly?

**EDIT:**  But I want to create **`circle`**, **`member1`** and **`member2`** and *their relationships* on the fly without worrying whether the nodes previously exist, but if they already do, just update them accordingly

---

**EDIT:** To make myself clearer after comments and suggestions from @DaveBennet @cybersam, & @MichaelHunger

(**MAIN AIM:**) **To create a relationship which implies that `member1` invited `member2` to join `circle3`**

1. If node(s)/relationship(s) DO NOT exist, create them
2. If node(s)/relationship(s) exist update them

***In all cases, there should be no duplicates of any nodes or relationships***

This shouldn't be as difficult as it's turning out. I'm really starting to think there's something that the documentation is failing to appropriately convey?

See also here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-create-unique.html

What confuses me is, why must there be an exact **node**-match before the `match...merge`/`match...create unique` query can return rows? doesn't that defeat the purpose of the query itself?... especially on the ***create*** aspect?

I even created a node as follows

```
create (member:Member) return member
```

Then attempted the following query - knowing fully well that by now, a `member` node would already exist, though without any properties(e.g `id` as shown below)

```
match (member:Member {id:1})
create unique (member) -[memberOf:IS_MEMBER_OF {time:timestamp()}]-> (circle:Circle {id:3, cycleId:5, creator:member.id}) 
return member, circle, memberOf
```

I believe this should search for a member node with id = 1... this wouldn't exist, so it should go ahead and create the new `member` node with it's properties, plus the defined relationship(s), plus any other required node(s).

To my surprise, this still returns (no rows).

So, please i'll appreciate if someone points me towards achieving the stated aim, clearly explaining to me why what I've attempted won't work and why the proposed solution would work.

Thanks.

Comment: the `match` statement must match something or nothing will happen. you could replace the `match` with a `merge` in the first line and the **circle** node will be created.

Comment: Also, you cannot use a node (`circle`) as a property value. So, even if your `MATCH` did find a match, you'd get an error for the `MERGE`. You need to rethink what you are trying to do and your data model.

Comment: @Dave Bennet, if like you say, ***the `match` statement must match something or nothing will happen***... Then, permit me to ask what is the essence of the `match... merge` query?... shouldn't it insert if a match isn't found?

Comment: in your query the `merge` statement will be executed for every node/row returned by the `match`. However, since the **circle** node does not exist yet, no rows are returned and the `merge` statement is never executed. The `merge` phrase by itself will attempt to make a match and if it does not make one then create what could not be found.  As cybersam says assigning the **circle** node as a value to the *c* attribute in the relationship won't work. Do you want the result to resemble `(member)-[:INVITED_TO_JOIN]->(circle)`? i.e. relationship is between the circle/member?

Comment: @DaveBennett,  please see my latest Edit to the question

Comment: @cybersam,  please see my latest Edit to the question

Answer (score 2):

You very probably want to connect those two members via an inviation node.

```
match (circle:Circle {id:3, cycleId:5})
match (member1:Member {id:1})
match (member2:Member {id:2})
create (invite:Invite {time:timestamp()})-[:TO_CIRCLE]->(circle)
create (invite)-[:INVITED_BY]->(member1)
create (invite)-[:INVITED]->(member2)
return member1, member2, invite, circle;
```

Otherwise if you just want to record the fact:

```
match (circle:Circle {id:3, cycleId:5})
match (member1:Member {id:1})
match (member2:Member {id:2})
merge (member1)-[r:MEMBER]->(circle)
on create set r.since = timestamp(), r.by = member2.id
```

Comment: 1st query still returns (no rows) while 2nd query returns (no changes, no rows).

Comment: please see my latest Edit to the question

Answer (score 2):

The `MATCH` clause ONLY succeeds if there is a match, and aborts the entire query if there is no match. `OPTIONAL MATCH`, on the other hand, never aborts the query (and gives `NULL` values to anything not matched).

Unfortunately, the `MERGE` clause does not support a pattern in which a node has 3 relationships -- as would be required by the `invite` node in @MichaelHunger's suggested answer. This is because a pattern can only express 2 relationships per node, and `MERGE` does not accept multiple (comma-separated) patterns.

This query, which uses a data model similar to @MichaelHunger's, might work for you:

```
MERGE (circle:Circle { id:3, cycleId:5 })
MERGE (member1:Member { id:1 })
MERGE (member2:Member { id:2 })
WITH circle, member1, member2
OPTIONAL MATCH (member1)<-[:INVITED_BY]-(invite:Invite)-[:INVITED]->(member2), (invite)-[:TO_CIRCLE]->(circle)
WITH circle, member1, member2,
  CASE
    WHEN invite IS NULL THEN [1]
    ELSE NULL END AS doit
FOREACH (ignored IN doit | 
  CREATE (i:Invite { time:timestamp()})-[:TO_CIRCLE]->(circle),(member1)<-[:INVITED_BY]-(i)-[:INVITED]->(member2))
WITH circle, member1, member2
MATCH (member1)<-[:INVITED_BY]-(invite:Invite)-[:INVITED]->(member2), (invite)-[:TO_CIRCLE]->(circle)
RETURN member1, member2, invite, circle;
```

This query uses a handy, but tricky, workaround involving `OPTIONAL MATCH`, `CASE`, and `FOREACH` clauses.

The `MATCH` at the end is needed to re-find the right `Invite` node so that the query can return it, as any identifiers defined within a `FOREACH` clause are invisible outside of that clause.